# Prevent vee-validate set dirty with data from API response

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

My problem is that I need to prevent users from leave a page when the form is `dirty` and ask then if they want to save changes before leave. But, using vee-validate, the form is `dirty` when its filled with data from API response and I need to set the form `dirty` just when user change a value on form. I tried sets programmatically but the dirty remains true.

I also tried to use `touched`, but it seems not work with vue-multiselect

Maybe `dirty` its not exactly what I need, but the same problem happens using `changed` for example

This is how I tried to programmatically change the `dirty` state:

```
Object.keys(this.$refs.form.fields).forEach(
  (key) => (this.$refs.form.fields[key].dirty = false)
)
```

I also tried change only the form flag

```
this.$refs.form.flags.dirty = false
```

but without success

Answer (score 0):

You can use [resetForm](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/components/handling-forms#resetting-forms-after-submit)

This will automatically set the dirty flag to `false`.

If you want to manipulate the form after you have set the values, you must use [resetField](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/use-field)